# Setting Library path in Mac OS

Tags: postgresql, binary, rpath, install-name-tool

I am trying to generate a relocatable binary for Postgresql and I'm having difficulty library path set for libpq. I have an linux script which uses LD_RUN_PATH and it is setting the right library path for all the generated binaries. Take a look at the snippet

```bash
export LD_RUN_PATH='$ORIGIN/../lib'

make clean
make install-world-contrib-recurse -j
```

Since there is no LD_RUN_PATH on macos I'm finding it difficult to replicate this behaviour by default the Library path is setting to **/Users/dummy/Desktop/postgres/build/mac_build/lib/libpq.5.11.dylib**. I know that I can change it using install_name_tool -change but I would need to change it for all the binaries generated by postgres one by one. So what I want to know is there a way to do this just like linux by setting a variable or giving some extra params to make. I tried looking in the internet but couldn't find a reasonable solution